# Swift Best way to check for nil in collection type

Tags: arrays, swift

I was hoping something like `anArray.contains(nil)` would work but it doesn't.

The best I can do is create an extension like this:

```
extension Array {
    func containsNil() -> Bool {
        return self.filter({ $0 == nil }).count > 0
    }
}
```

Any other thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do if it contains `nil`?

Comment: What is your use case?  Only Arrays that can contain optionals can contain `nil`.  Do you want to protect against `nil` values?  If so, just flatten the array: `let vals:[Int?] = [1,2,3,nil]; let flat = vals.flatMap{$0} as [Int?];`

Comment: The reason you have now two comments asking about the use-case is because this is in almost all certainty an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244435).

Comment: Typo in my above code: you don't need as [Int?]

Answer (score 1):

You extension will always have to go through all elements, to count the number of `nil` elements. And return if the count is greater than 0. You're gathering more information than you need. You don't seem to use the count of nil elements. All you care is if there is a nil inside the array.

Instead you could simply iterate through the array, and are return true the first time you find `nil`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but that requires more lines of code. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: If you really want it short, you could just do: `.contains { $0 == nil }`. But check the comments on your question first. As nhgrif mentioned, it probably is a XY problem.